# Generate SQL from diagram view

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2000 Management Studio you could open a table and go into diagram view and generate SQL from that. How would you do that in SQL Server Management studio 2008 from diagram view?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your generate SQL refers to generate the create statement and you already have the table created.

1. Login to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
2. Open your Object Explorer, Databases
3. Right click on the Database name and "Script Database as", "Create to", "New Query Editor Window"

Note that you don't get the data from there